# Error on gem version when installing

Tags: ruby, rubygems, github-pages

I am trying to install the [github-pages gem](https://github.com/github/pages-gem) on Ubuntu 14.04.

I get this error about the version of a dependency (with or without sudo doesn't change the outcome):

```
$ sudo gem2.0 install github-pages

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
Unable to resolve dependencies: github-pages-health-check requires public_suffix (~> 1.4)
```

However, doing `gem2.0 list --local` shows me:

```
public_suffix (2.0.4)
```

What's the problem here? I have 2 coexisting versions of ruby (ruby1.9.3 and ruby2.0), but I have made `/usr/bin/ruby` link to ruby2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~>` is a [pessimistic](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rubys-pessimistic-operator) version constraint. `~> 1.4` means `>= 1.4` and `< 2.0`, and your version of `public_suffix` is not in that range. Try

```
gem install public_suffix -v 1.5.3
```

which is the newest version that actually satisfies the constraint.

Comment: Thanks, not a ruby user, I didn't know this pessimistic operator... I had temporary "fixed" (avoided) the problem by installing a newer version of ruby with `rvm`.